# Using XmlTextWriter to get a certain formatted output

Tags: xml, format

using XmlTextWriter I get this output:

(kennung klasse ="MELDID">12345</kennung klasse ="MELDID")

but I need this:

(kennung klasse ="MELDID">12345</kennung)

Think of ( is < and ) is > because it malformats my output here  ;-)

How do I get it this way? I am using a XmlTextWriter :

```
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
                xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

...
I am using this for the above line:

```
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("kennung klasse ='MELDID'".Replace("'", "\""), txtMeldID.Text);
```

How do I get the format I need? I tried various approaches with WriteElementString and WriteAttributeString but somehow can't get it right...

Thanks a lot

Eric

P.S.:

Same Problem here, output is

```
<hmm name="BerichtseinheitID">
  <wert>05</wert>
</hmm name="BerichtseinheitID">
```

but I need

```
<hmm name="BerichtseinheitID">
  <wert>05</wert>
</hmm>
```

My code here is

```
        private void XMLWriteRowHelpProperty(XmlWriter xmlTextWriter, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
        {
            xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement($"hmm name='{fieldName}'".Replace("'", "\""));
            xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("wert", fieldValue);
            xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use LINQ to XML to compose XML on the fly.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    string wert = "05";
    string name = "BerichtseinheitID";

    XElement xml = new XElement("hmm", 
                        new XAttribute("name", name),
                        new XElement("wert",wert)
                         );
    Console.Write(xml);
}
```

**Output**

```
<hmm name="BerichtseinheitID">
  <wert>05</wert>
</hmm>
```